# List name server from resolv.conf with hostname in one line per host

Tags: bash, networking, ansible, hosts

I need to get the DNS server(s) from my network, I tried using:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: check resolv.conf exists
      stat:
        path: /etc/resolv.conf
      register: resolv_conf
    - name: check nameservers list in resolv.conf
      debug:
        msg: "{{ contents }}"
      vars:
        contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') | regex_findall('\\s*nameserver\\s*(.*)') }}"
      when: resolv_conf.stat.exists == True
```

But this does not quite gives the result I need.

Will it be possible to write a playbook in such a way that the result looks like the below?

> hostname;dns1;dns2;dnsN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration below gives the list of nameservers

```yaml
nameservers: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf').splitlines()|
                 select('match', '^nameserver.*$')|
                 map('split', ' ')|
                 map('last')|list }}"
```

You can join the hostname and the items on the list

```yaml
msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ nameservers|join(';') }}"
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    nameservers: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf').splitlines()|
                     select('match', '^nameserver.*$')|
                     map('split', ' ')|
                     map('last')|list }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: nameservers
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ inventory_hostname }};{{ nameservers|join(';') }}
```

---

2. The simplified declaration below works fine if there is no `nameserver.*` in the comments

```yaml
nameservers: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf')|
                 regex_findall('\\s*nameserver\\s*(.*)') }}"
```

Unfortunately, the Linux default file */etc/resolv.conf* contains the comment:

| # run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

This regex will match `nameservers.`

```yaml
nameservers:
  - s.
```

You can solve this problem by putting at least one space behind the keyword `nameserver`.

```yaml
                 regex_findall('\\s*nameserver\\s+(.*)') }}"
```

However, this won't help if there is the keyword `nameserver` in the comment.

---

Q: ***"No filter named 'split'"***

A: There is no filter *split* in Ansible less than 2.11. Use *regex_replace* instead

```yaml
nameservers: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf').splitlines()|
                 select('match', '^nameserver.*$')|
                 map('regex_replace', '^(.*) (.*)$', '\\2')|list }}"
```

Comment: fatal: [10.0.3.103]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf').splitlines()| select('match', '^nameserver.*$')| map('split', ' ')| map('last')|list }}'. Error was a <class 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError'>, original message: no filter named 'split'"}

Comment: Use *regex_replace* instead. I added the example.

Comment: I have problem with output. it looks like i see a local resolv.conf file not the ones on hosts.

Comment: Sure. *lookup* works on the localhost only. Your problem is `hosts: localhost`. Open a new question if you want to work on remote hosts. It's a completely different problem.

Comment: I don't really understand, I need to check this file on many hosts that I have in inventory.

Comment: Which part, in particular, you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand why as a result I get the DNS addresses I have in my local resolv.conf not the ones from inventory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249418/discussion-between-masterzst-and-vladimir-botka).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `regex_findall` already creates you a list with all DNS servers, you just need to add the hostname to that list and [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) the whole list with a semicolon.

```yaml
- name: check nameservers list in resolv.conf
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        (
          [ ansible_hostname ] +
          lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf', errors='ignore')
            | regex_findall('\s*nameserver\s*(.*)')
        ) | join(';')
      }}
```

Which will result in something like (`b176263884e6` being the actual hostname of a container):

```
TASK [check nameservers list in resolv.conf] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: b176263884e6;1.1.1.1;4.4.4.4;8.8.8.8
```

---

Note that you don't even need the `stat` task, as you can ignore errors of the lookup with [`errors='ignore'`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins).

This will, then, give you only the hostname, along with a warning:

```
TASK [check nameservers list in resolv.conf] *****************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/etc/resolv.conf' in expected paths 
(use -vvvvv to see paths)
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: b176263884e6
```

Comment: Put at least one space behind the keyword to avoid matching *nameservers* in the potential comment `\s*nameserver\s+(.*)`. Still, this regex will match the potential *nameserver* in the comments.

Comment: After try run yml: The offending line appears to be:

      {{
         (
         ^ here